# GitHub Private Repository not taking Xcode pushes

Tags: xcode, github

Currently I'm working on a Xcode project and committing/pushing to my local/remote GitHub repo. Everything was set up smoothly and ran smoothly, that is until I decided to change my GitHub repo from public to private. My local commits still work smoothly, but when I try to push to GitHub, everything will seem as if it ran smoothly, but when I go on my GitHub to see if the push has been updated, there's nothing. The last commit I see is from before I turned the repo to private.

I've also tried to delete the original repo and start fresh by committing to a private repo on the initial commit. But no luck.

Has anyone else also experienced this?
Does anyone know of a solution to this other than to revert the repo back to public?

Comment: Hey, GitHub private repos are now free! Cool!!! Thanks for the heads-up! — Okay, so as to your actual question, I've no idea. But I do know that Xcode git support sucks. So my question would be, what happens if, instead of using Xcode, you use git _itself_? Do your push from the command line instead of from Xcode. Does that fix it?

Comment: Another idea; what if you delete your github account from Xcode's preferences and then add it again. Does _that_ fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue "The remote repository could not be accessed" but now it works properly. The solution is to go to the Xcode Setting delete the GitHub Account and then generate the token, then paste the token in Xcode where you are doing account sign in